# How to make function which takes block as parameter and one boolean and in body if boolean is true executes that block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

How do you make a  function which takes block as parameter and one boolean and in body; and if the boolean is true executes that block ?

The Block has no returning value ( void ) and does not take any parameter.

In c++ I would do this with function pointers but I am new to objective c and don't know how to perform conditional execution of blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your method as

```
-(void)myBlock:(void (^)(void))block withCondition:(BOOL)condition{
    if(condition){
       block();
    }
}
```

Call it as:

```
[self myBlock:^(void) {
        NSLog(@"Hii block excuted");
    } withCondition:YES];
```

For more detail you can find it in [HERE](http://www.appcoda.com/objective-c-blocks-tutorial/)

Comment: iHulk, the label on the parameter `WithCondition' should start with a lower-case letter to follow Cocoa naming conventions. I edited your answer to reflect that.

Comment: @DuncanC my bad, its just a typing mistake. but thanks

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C Method:

```
- (void)executeBlock:(void (^)(void))block onCondition:(BOOL)condition
{
    if (condition)
    {
        block();
    }
}
```

C function:

```
void executeBlock(void (^block)(void), BOOL condition)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        block();
    }
}
```